# Reading bytes from socket to byte array

Tags: c#, java, sockets, networking

I'm working a client/server application where I have to read bytes from the data received on the server. I'm trying to convert it from Java to C# but I can't seem to solve this one! T

Java code:

```
byte[] bucket = new byte[4];
this.socket.getInputStream().read(bucket, 0, 2);
```

And now I need the same code in C#! Hope you can help me out!

Comment: Nothing much, I've been googling around but I'm still in the process of learning a lot, I don't really know how to tackle the problem!

Comment: @FabianPas First try something. If you still have problems, we will be here to help.

Comment: Am I right to create a new NetworkStream object with my Socket and just use the Read method from that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a like-for-like port, the most sensible thing is probably to wrap the socket in a `NetworkStream`, which then acts a lot like the `getInputStream` result (except you would only do it once), i.e.

```
var ns = new NetworkStream(socket);
...
int bytesRead = ns.Read(bucket, 0, 2);
```

but remember to ensure that `ns` is disposed when you are done (ideally via `using`). If you want to use the socket directly, you'll have to use the `Receive` method on the socket.

Comment: If I use socket.Receive will it only allocate the first 4 bytes of the message because that's the size of the byte array? And what if I wanted to receive a certain offset?

Comment: @Fabian there are other overloads to receive. The call to Read currently only reads 2 bytes (max), btw - and could be less. To quote from java docs: Reads up to len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read, possibly zero. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.

Comment: @Fabian in fact, I'd say that the fact that your java code doesn't capture the return value tells me the java code is buggy.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use  [TCP Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx).

```
   TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
   NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
   Byte[] data = new Byte[4;
   stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

**EDIT**: Assuming, you already have access to socket, try below (use [Socket#Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx)):

```
   byte[] bucket = new byte[4];
   int bytesRec = socket.Receive(bucket);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's actually the server that receives the data, I only have access to a socket.

Comment: @FabianPas: Updated the answer. Please let me know, if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a super-simple http server implementation here in the example code for [System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx). The example shows how to read from the socket.